# Fix power line frequency for my webcam

Tags: ubuntu, camera

I have acquired a new Aukey webcam to use with my Ubunty computer.

Whenever I use it with my lights on, the video keeps flickering.
I have done some research, obviously this is linked to the frequency of the power lines in my country (50Hz in France).

However, none of the fixes I found make any difference to the situation

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

Returns

```
Synaptics RMI4 Touch Sensor (rmi4:rmi4-00.fn54):
    /dev/v4l-touch0

Aukey-PC-LM1E Camera: Aukey-PC- (usb-0000:00:14.0-2):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3

Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-8):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

And

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 --get-ctrl=power_line_frequency
```

Returns `1`, as it should. Changing it to any other value (as documented in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581867/how-can-i-change-my-webcams-power-line-frequency-setting)) doesn't make any difference.
But when I change the brightness using v4l2, I can see the difference so the changes seem to be applied...
I have no idea what elese I can do

If that is relevant, I am using an external monitor.